# creating a temp table in a database using the values in a sas data set

Tags: sas, temp-tables

can anyone help me with the syntax of creating a temp table in a database with the values from a SAS data set ? I want to use this temp table next to join with other tables in the database.

```
libname X odbc dsn=aaabbb uid=abcd pwd=efgh quote_char=''; 

data X.vishtest;   
set test.noosbtest; 
run;
```

I want to create 'vishtest' as a temp table with the values in a SAS data set 'test.noosbtest'.

I have created a temp table in an earlier attempt like the following and deleting the values in it, but next I am unable to put the values of sas data set into this temp table :

```
select * from connection to X(Create temp table vishtest as select var1 from table1 limit 20); 

select * from connection to X(delete from tempdb.vishwatemp a);
```

Comment: What type of database is the ODBC libname connecting to?

Comment: Database is on Netezza server. The second set of code as following                                                            select * from connection to X(Create temp table vishtest as select var1 from table1 limit 20); 
select * from connection to X(delete from tempdb.vishwatemp a);
 This is creating a temp table vishtest from another existing table with some 20 rows of data and I am deleting the contents of the temp table vishtest. It works fine till here...but next,I want to input values to this temp table from a SAS data set which is on my local drive or lib, which I am unable to do.

Comment: The easiest thing, as far as I can tell, would be to delete the existing temp table and simply make a new one - would that work?  I'd do that as `proc sql; drop table X.vishwatemp; create table X.vishwatemp as (select * from test.noosbtest);`

Comment: since test.noosbtest is on my local drive, it is not recognizing the 'test' libname which is pointing to my local drive. Because first to create a temp table, first I need to specify the connection parameters to the netezza and then follows the "(select * from test.noosbtest); " statement which is not working

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that your local sas data set has the same columns as your database table.

If your existing database table is X.my_table and your local dataset is mylib.the_data, you can try this:

```
proc sql;
    create table X.my_table_empty like X.my_table;
    create table the_data_empty like mylib.the_data;
quit;
proc compare
    data = my_table_empty
    compare = the_data_empty;
run;
```

If proc compare comes back and tells you that the two tables are identical, then you should be able to load your data table into the temp table:

```
proc append
    base = X.my_table_empty
    data = mylib.the_data;
run;
```

> Original answer:
>
> > > This is creating a temp table vishtest from another existing table
> > >       with some 20 rows of data and I am deleting the contents of the temp
> > >       table vishtest. It works fine till here...but next,I want to input
> > >       values to this temp table from a SAS data set which is on my local
> > >       drive or lib, which I am unable to do
> >
> > If vishtest contains the same columns as your sas dataset, then this
> >     may work for you:
> >
> > ```
> > proc append
> >     base = X.vishtest
> >     data = test.noosbtest;
> > run;
> > ```

Comment: My logic to create a temp table is ...create a temp table from any existing table on netezza with few records like 10 records or so...and then delete the contents in this new temp table...next step is to load this temp table with the data from sas data set located in my local drive.